# How display a list of suppressed PC-Lint warning types

Tags: pc-lint

Looking for a way for PC-Lint to display all the suppressed warning types after PC-lint has completed.

Context: Working on a large older project and there have been a couple of warning types that were suppressed (-e#) and not restored appropriately. Looking for a way to find more issues of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to do this with PC-Lint. But I have seen grep being used for this purpose. We allowed suppressions as long as there were documented and we had a script to extract all such comments. It's not that difficult to write a regexp for this.